# my font haven't be shown in print preview stimulsoft

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report, stimulsoft

I am using StimulSoft software for showing reports in my asp.net mvc project.
In my report all of things is OK, but In print preview my font haven't be applied.
I attached my font in `report.cshtml` file by using `font-face`.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Create a print style in you css using `@media print { ..... }`

Comment: @garethb In StimulSoft it doesn't worked!

Comment: @Majid Basirati, 1-If you use other web browser on same workstation problem exist? 2-when you preview it with HTML Preview the characters do show up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In old versions; as @Abbas-Mirzaei said, you have to install fonts on server.
stimulsoft reports.net doesn't support import or embed fonts before 2016 versions.
but in newer version you can add fonts.

```
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(@"d:\Work\Resources\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add font in project for example(fonts folder) then add this code into your service

```
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~/fonts/my-font/font-name.ttf"));
```

Then add your fonts to server font folder too!

Answer (score 1):

Add font in Controller for load in Razor pages:

```
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(@"d:\Work\Resources\glyphicons-halflings- 
regular.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too...you can add your fonts to server font folder if you access to it...(c:\windows\fonts)

Comment: No, I don't access to server!

Comment: you know..you should add font to windows because stimulsoft dosent read from your app font it reads from windows font

Comment: Tell your Server Administrator that install your font and check it....or use 'Tahoma' or other default font in your report....

Comment: I have added my font to font folder  in my system. but my font haven't be shown in "stimul report print preview" in local too!

Comment: which version of stimulsoft did you use?and which dll of stimul did you add to your project?

Comment: I have added my font (B Nazanin) to font folder in my server. but my font haven't be shown in "stimul report print preview" in server! (but in local it works). my stimulsoft version is 2019.3.5 and my dlls in bin folder are Stimulsoft.Base.dll, Stimulsoft.Report.dll, Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.dll and Stimulsoft.Report.Web.dll

Comment: Was your problem fixed? @MajidBasirati