# How to Add Font File to Stimulsoft report from embedded font in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, embed, stimulsoft

I use C# WPF and Stimulsoft

I want to send path my font file was embedded to my report when need to show

I have embedded font in **my WPF Project** and I use it like this :

**in XAML :**

```
<Label x:Name="preloader" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Loading . . ." Margin="319,178,48,34" FontFamily="/WpfApp5;component/FNT/#B Titr" FontSize="48" Background="White"/>
```

The font was embed from font's folder in my project :

[image]

for my report was generated in stimulsoft I cannot embed font but I can send it a path of my font
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943264/my-font-havent-be-shown-in-print-preview-stimulsoft)

by this I **can send it my font path** :

[image]

for that I tried two way

**C# Code :**

1- :

```
StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(@"pack://application:,,,/FNT/#B Titr");
```

this case will show this error :

*System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'*

2-  :

```
var fntpath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WpfApp5.FNT.BTITRBD.TTF");
            StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(fntpath.ToString());
```

*and in this fntpath.ToString() is null !*

How to do this ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddFontFile` method expects the path of a physical file on disk. You cannot pass in a `pack:` URI, because it doesn't understand that format. And you cannot just call `.ToString()` on a `Stream`, since that won't produce any meaningful information.

You need to extract your font file to a temporary file, and pass the path to that file to the `AddFontFile` method.

```cs
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string fileName = "WpfApp5.FNT.BTITRBD.TTF";
string fontPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName);
if (!File.Exists(fontPath))
{
    using (var stream = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(fileName))
    using (var output = File.Create(fontPath))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(output);
    }
}

StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(fontPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var report = new StiReport();
var reportPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath($@"~/Reports/{reportItem.FileName}");
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath($@"~/fonts/Samim.ttf"));
Stimulsoft.Base.StiFontCollection.AddFontFile(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath($@"~/fonts/IRANSansWeb.ttf"));
report.Load(reportPath);
report.RegBusinessObject("customer", customerModel);
report.RegBusinessObject("receipt", receiptModel);
report.RegBusinessObject("order", orderModel);
report.Render(false);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).